# PHP recursively find files and folders and create HTML

Tags: php, html, recursion

Basically what I am trying to do is take a base directory (already defined) and recursively go down it, making a link in a navbar for files and a collapsible for directories; under the collapsible would be links for files in that directory and possibly more collapsibles for directories inside the directory. Here is what I have so far, which is not working:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
    if ($file->isDot()) continue;
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"#!\">" . $file .  "</a></li>"; /*This successfully 
    creates links named from all the files in the directory specified by $dir */
          }
    if ($file->isDir()) {
        ?>
        <li class="no-padding">
            <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                <li>
                    <a class="collapsible-header"><?php echo $file->getFilename(); ?></a>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <ul> 
                           <?php 
                               $dir2 = $file->getFilename();
                               foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir."/".$dir2) as $file1) {
                                    if ($file1->isDot()) continue;
                                   if ($file1->isFile()) {
                            echo "<li><a href='#' class=\"mui-btn mui-btn-primary waves-effect waves-teal\">".$file1 . "</a></li>";  }
                               } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <?php
    }
}
        ?>
```

However, for some reason it seems a DirectoryIterator within a DirectoryIterator is no good (the $dir2 was for test purposes). Or I could have a syntax issue. The reason I want this to work this way is because I want the files to be contained in `<li><a href="#!">file</a></li>` html and the files under a directory to be in `<li><a href='#' class="mui-btn mui-btn-primary waves-effect waves-teal">file-in-folder</a></li>` format.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know! Thanks!

EDIT: I changed $1file to $file1 and it works fine, even appended the dir; however, I basically want something like a for loop that will keep creating the collapsibles within each other if there is still a directory present. Basically so it would automatically create the formatting if I had:

```
Dir1 (main) >
   File 1 //link
   File 2 //link
   Dir 1 > //collapsible header
      File 1.1 //collapsible button
      File 1.2 //...
      Dir 2 >
        File 2.1
        File 2.2
   Dir 3
```

Without me having to write 10 nested DirectoryIterators, just in case you can go down that far.

Comment: `$1file` - this is an issue, you can't start a variable name with a number. Call it $file1 or something

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an invalid variable name. PHP accepts variables starting with letters and underscore followed by other chars. Try $file1 instead of $1file 
Cheers!
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

This is my logic, probably you can get some idea from here.

if your main folder looks like this

[image]

then here is the code to get the folder structures.

```
echo '<pre>';
$dir='folders';
$files = array_slice(scandir($dir), 2);
foreach($files as $k=>$file){
$dir1=$dir.'/'.$file;
if(is_dir($dir1)){
    $files1 = array_slice(scandir($dir1), 2);
    if(!$files1){
        $FOLDERS[$file]=$file;
    }else{
        foreach($files1 as $kk=>$file1){
            $dir2=$dir1.'/'.$file1;
            $files2 = array_slice(scandir($dir2), 2);
            if(!$files2){
                $FOLDERS[$file][$file1]=$file1;
            }else{
                foreach($files2 as $file2){
                    $FOLDERS[$file][$file1][$file2]=$file2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
print_r($FOLDERS);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [folder1] => folder1
    [folder2] => Array
        (
        [folder3] => Array
            (
                [folder4] => folder4
            )

        [folder5] => folder5
        [folder6] => folder6
    )
```

)

i used it only to scan the folders, you can extend it according to your needs.